# Reverting an object back to mirrored state (for symmetrical editing) after "APPLY" in Modifier panel was used

Tags: modifiers

1. I created an animal body using planes, extruded it, then mirrored the extrusion. 2. I then clicked "APPLY" in the modifier panel so that I could extrude the legs individually in different positions on either side of the mirrored halves. Everything is fine up to here
2. Now I need to get back to where I can edit with symmetry (like you can do right after a mirror) and I can't find how to do that.

Comment: you can symmetrize your object (Mesh > Symmetrize) or cut half of your object and use the Mirror modifier again, but in both case you will loose the unsymmetrical half you've created, is it what you want? It's not clear

Answer (score 0):

Delete half of your mesh, add a mirror modifier. Now you can tweak your mesh and all changes will be replicated across the selected axis.